# How do I change the menu items that appear in all applications' system menu?

Tags: always-on-top, systemmenu

The system menu of every application in my version of Windows 7 has the following menu items: Restore, Move, Size, Minimize, Maximize, and Close. I want to add one more item to all applications named "Always on Top". Is this possible? And in what language? (I know Java)